# How to parse this complex JSON object with functions inside

Tags: json, typescript, jsonparser

I got this code sample and would like to know how the suited MOJO (JSON Object) looks like? It consists of an array of complex JSON structure.

```
{
    'inputContext': undefined,
    'intents': {
        //Default Welcome Intent
        'LaunchRequest': async (conv: AdfConversation) => {

        },
        'ExitIntent': async (conv: AdfConversation) => {

        },
        'DefaultFallbackIntent': async (conv: AdfConversation) => {

        },
        'Unhandled': (conv: AdfConversation) => {

        },
    },
},
{
    'inputContext': ConversationContexts.WELCOME,
    'intents': {
        'BargainIntent': async (conv: AdfConversation) => {
            conv.setContext(ConversationContexts.BARGAIN)
            conv.ask('Du hast dich für das Schnäppchen entschieden.', ':tell')
        },
        'PodcastIntent': async (conv: AdfConversation) => {
            conv.setContext(ConversationContexts.PODCAST)
            if(conv.type){
                conv._alexaContext!.emitWithState('PodcastIntent',ConversationContexts.PODCAST)
            }
        },     
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not JSON. It's part of an an actual array object. Just assign it:

```
const a = [{
    'inputContext': undefined,
    'intents': {
        //Default Welcome Intent
        'LaunchRequest': async (conv: AdfConversation) => {

        },
        'ExitIntent': async (conv: AdfConversation) => {

        },
        'DefaultFallbackIntent': async (conv: AdfConversation) => {

        },
        'Unhandled': (conv: AdfConversation) => {

        },
    },
},
{
    'inputContext': ConversationContexts.WELCOME,
    'intents': {
        'BargainIntent': async (conv: AdfConversation) => {
            conv.setContext(ConversationContexts.BARGAIN)
            conv.ask('Du hast dich für das Schnäppchen entschieden.', ':tell')
        },
        'PodcastIntent': async (conv: AdfConversation) => {
            conv.setContext(ConversationContexts.PODCAST)
            if(conv.type){
                conv._alexaContext!.emitWithState('PodcastIntent',ConversationContexts.PODCAST)
            }
        },     
    },
}];
```